# Fine-tune label placement for road shields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want to display road shields and road numbers within them. I already checked the option to connect multiple lines in order to avoid double placement, set the minimal length for lines to be labeled to 5mm and I even limited the absolute number of sign to 25 but it still looks cluttered on some roads whereas some have no sign at all. Even if restrict the above mentioned settings even more, I still get weird looking double labels like in picture 2.

[image: moderate limits to label placement --> minimum line length 6mm, max 30 parts to label]

[image: strict limits to label placements --> minimum line length 12mm, max 30 parts to label]

Comment: Could you provide screenshots of your settings for convenience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes using the option to connect multiple lines under the Rendering in labeling as well as setting the minimal length for lines to be labeled do not work for unknown reason. Therefore, the only solution to this as I faced the same issue many times is to merge the small lines together using Merge selected tool:

[image]

Here is the labeled line before using Merge selected tool:

[image]

Here is the labeled line after using Merge selected tool:

[image]